# Concatenar texto y una variable de un data.frame en R

Tags: r

Necesito construir el intervalo IN para una consulta sql en RODBC.

Manualmente, línea a línea sería:

```
capitales <- paste(capitales, capitalprovincia[1, "codigo.capital.ine"], sep="")
capitales <- paste(capitales, ", ", sep="")
capitales <- paste(capitales, capitalprovincia[2, "codigo.capital.ine"], sep="")
capitales <- paste(capitales, ", ", sep="")
capitales <- paste(capitales, capitalprovincia[3, "codigo.capital.ine"], sep="")
```

He intentado iterar con for pero este es el error:

```
  Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i, y) : 
    objeto 'codigo.capital.ine' no encontrado
```

Esta es la función donde,
`codigo.capital.ine` es una columna.
`capitalprovincia` es el data frame:

```
capitales <- "(";
concatenarvariableSQLIN <- function (x, y) 
 for (i in 1:nrow(x))
  {
   capitales <- paste(capitales, x[i, y], sep="")
   capitales <- paste(capitales, ", ", sep="")
  }
capitales <- concatenarvariableSQLIN(capitalprovincia, codigo.capital.ine)
capitales <- paste(capitales, ")", sep="")
```

`capitalprovincia` es un dataframe:

```
str(capitalprovincia)
'data.frame':   52 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ codproine           : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ codmunine           : int  59 3 14 13 19 15 40 19 59 37 ...
 $ municipio           : chr  "Vitoria-Gasteiz" "Albacete" "Alicante/Alacant" "Almería" ...
 $ codigo.capital.ine  : chr  "01059" "02003" "03014" "04013" ...
 $ codigo.provincia.ine: chr  "01" "02" "03" "04" ...
 $ codigo.municipio.ine: chr  "059" "003" "014" "013" ...
```

Saludos.

Comment: En el código que agregaste a tu pregunta no se ve como se inicializa `capitalprovincia`, podrías por favor agregar la salida de `str(capitalprovincia)` ? también el código completo de `concatenarvariableSQLIN`.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, he añadido la estructura del data.frame ```capitalprovincia``` a la pregunta, y por otro lado, el texto completo de ```concatenarvariableSQLIN``` es el que se muestra.  gracias.